# $A$ is $n\times n$ real matrix with $A^2=-I$ , to prove that $n$ is even

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with real entries such that $A^2=-I$ , then how do we prove that $n$ is even ? ( All I know about this matrix is that it has no real eigenvalues )

Answer (score 3):

We know that the determinant of $A^2$ and determinant of $-I$ are equal. Determinant of $-I$ has to be nonnegative, which leads us to $n$ being even.