# Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries such that $A^2 + I = 0$ then $n$ is even.

Tags: linear-algebra, cyclic-groups, jordan-normal-form, cyclic-decomposition

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries such that $A^2 + I = 0$ then $n$ is even. And if $n = 2k$, then $A$ is similar over the field of real numbers to a matrix of the block form

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0      & -I \\
    I & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$ 
where $I$ is the $k \times k$ identity matrix.

I have done the first part. Since $\det(A^2) = \det (-I)$ we must have $\det (-I)$ non negative and hence $n$ must be even.

Need Help in the second part.

Thank You.

Comment: I think that $A^2 + I = 0$, eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm i$. Since $A$ is an $n \times n$ real matrix, $n$ is even.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can solve both parts of the question at the same time as follows: Given $A$, define a map $\mathbb C\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ by $(u+iv,x)\mapsto (u+iv)\cdot x:=ux+vAx$. Evidently, this is linear over $\mathbb R$ in both components and satisfies $(1,x)\mapsto x$. Using that $A^2=-I$, one easily verifies that it is multiplicative, i.e. $z\cdot (w\cdot x)=(zw)\cdot x$. Hence is satisfies all properties required from scalar multiplication, and hence makes $\mathbb R^n$ into a complex vector space, so $n=2m$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$. Moreover, choosing a complex basis $\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$ for this vector space, $\{x_1,\dots,x_m,i\cdot x_1,\dots,i\cdot x_m\}$ is a real basis for $\mathbb R^n$. By definition the matrix representation of $A$ with respect to this real basis is the block matrix you have indicated.

Answer (score 4):

Let $T$ be an operator on a $n$-dimensional real vector space $V$ satisfying $T^2+I=0$. We will prove that all such operators have a distinguished cyclic decomposition.

If $T^2+I=0$, then the polynomial $x^2+1$ annihilates $T$. Since this polynomial is irreducible (over the reals), it must be the minimal polynomial. The characteristic polynomial of $T$ must have the same irreducible factors as the minimal polynomial, so it must have the form $(x^2+1)^k$ for some positive integer $k$. Therefore its degree (the dimension of $V$) must be $n=2k$, that is, even. Now we consider the cyclic decomposition of $T$. In other words, we apply the cyclic decomposition theorem to $T$
to get a decomposition of $V$ as a (finite) direct sum of $T$-cyclic subspaces $Z(v,A)$ of $V$ with certain non-zero vectors $v\in V$. The $T$-annihilator of $v$ must divide the minimal polynomial, therefore it must equal $x^2+1$. Hence $(v,Tv)$ is a basis of $Z(v,T)$ such that the matrix of the compression of $T$ to $Z(v,T)$ is the companion matrix of the polynomial $x^2+1$, that is, the matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right).$$

Therefore the operator $T$ has the representation as a block diagonal matrix with $k$ blocks equal to the above matrix.

This argument shows that all operators $T$ on an $n$-dimensional real vector space satisfying $T^2+I=0$ have the same matrix in a direct sum of $k=2/n$ cyclic basis.

Therefore all $n\times n$ matrices $A$ satisfying $A^2+I=0$ are similar, in particular they are all similar to a $n\times n$-matrix of the form
$$B=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -I\\ I & 0\end{array}\right),$$
as $B$ also satisfies $B^2+I=0$, where $I$ is the $k\times k$ identity matrix and $n=2k$.

Comment: This is an Ex of Hoffman Kunze. Your proof is supposed to be "the" correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

$A^2=-I$. If $n$ is odd, taking determinants gives us
$$
(\det A)^2=\det (A^2)=\det(-I)=(-1)^n=-1.
$$ As $\det A$ is a real number, this is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

We can do both parts in one go, using some module theory (essentially @Alcides Buss's answer with a bit more detail towards the end).

Take $\mathbb F = \mathbb R$ and $V = \mathbb R^n$. Let $\alpha:V \to V$ be the endomorphism corresponding to the matrix $A $ and $V_\alpha$ the corresponding $\mathbb R[X]$-module. The rational canonical form theorem says that, as $\mathbb R$-modules,
$$
V_\alpha \cong \frac{\mathbb R[X]}{(f_1)} \oplus \frac{\mathbb R[X]}{(f_2)} \oplus \cdots \oplus \frac{\mathbb R[X]}{(f_s)},
$$
where $f_1 | f_2 | \cdots | f_s$. The minimal polynomial is $f_s$, and we know that since $\alpha^2 + \imath = 0$, the degree of the minimal polynomial cannot exceed 2. We can quite easily argue that the minimal polynomial cannot be degree 1, so $X^2 + 1$ is *a* minimal polynomial, and since minimal polynomials are unique up to a unit, $X^2 + 1$ is in fact *the* (monic) minimal polynomial.

So $f_s = X^2 + 1$. Since $X^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb R[X]$ and we need $f_1 | f_2 | \cdots | f_s$, we can WLOG conclude that $f_1 = f_2 = \cdots = f_s = X^2 + 1$ (technically, we could add as many $1$'s as we like to the front, but since $\mathbb R[X]/(1) \cong 0$, it doesn't change the direct sum).

The companion matrix of $X^2 + 1$ is
$$
c(X^2 + 1) =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Hence, there exists a basis of $V$ in which the matrix representing $\alpha$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
c(f_1) & & & \\
& c(f_2) & & \\
& & \ddots & \\
& & & c(f_s)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & & & &  \\
1 & 0 & & & & \\
& & 0 & -1 & &  \\
& & 1 & 0 & & \\
& & & & \ddots & \\
& & & & & 0 & -1  \\
& & & & & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}. \tag{$*$}
$$
It's clear then that $n$ is even.

At this point we can proceed in two ways:

1. We can see from the matrix $(*)$ that in this basis, say $\{v_1, \dots, v_k, v_{k+1}, \dots, v_{2k}\}$, the action of $\alpha$ is to map $v_{2i-1} \mapsto v_{2i}$ and $v_{2i}\mapsto -v_{2i-1}$ for each $i$ between $1$ and $k$. Now consider a new basis $\{v_1', \dots, v_k', v_{k+1}', \dots, v_{2k}'\}$ in which $v_1', \dots, v_k'$ are $v_1, v_3, \dots, v_{2k-1}$ (the odd-indexed basis vectors) respectively and $v_{k+1}', \dots, v_{2k}'$ are $v_2, v_4, \dots, v_{2k}$ (the even-indexed basis vectors) respectively. In the primed basis, you get the desired form
   $$
   M = \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & -I \\
   I & 0
   \end{pmatrix},
   $$
   and since this is related to $A$ by a change of basis, they are similar.
2. Alternatively, $M$ satisfies the equation $M^2 + I = 0$. Hence $A$ and $M$ are both similar to $(*)$, so they are similar to each other.

Answer (score -1):

I solve it another method : $det(A^2)=det(-I)=(-1)^n ....(1)$.

Now $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then ${\lambda}^2+I^2=0\Rightarrow \lambda =i,-i.$ So $detA=i(-i)=1\Rightarrow det(A^2)=(detA)^2=1 ....(2)$

So from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $n=2m$ for dome $m\in \mathbb{N} $

Comment: plz specify reason for downvote..(for any improvement)

Comment: I think $det(A)=i(-i)$ is not true, first of all, it's true that $\lambda = \pm i$, but is not necessarily true that both values must be eigenvalues, it could also be just $i$ or $-i$ with multiplicity. Furthermore, the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, counted with multiplicity. So even if both $i$ and $-i$ were eigenvalues the determinant would be $det(A)=i^k (-i)^j$ with $k+j=n$.