# An especial matrix is similar to an especial matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with real entries such that $A^{2}=-I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Then $n$ is even, and if $n=2k$, then $A$ is similar over the field of real numbers to a matrix of the block form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}‎
‎0 &‎ -l_{k} \\‎
‎l_{k} & 0
‎\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where $l_{k}$ is the $k\times k$ identity matrix.

Why? How?

Comment: $\text{det}(A^2)=\text{det}(-I)=(-1)^n\text{det}(I)=(-1)^n$. Since $\text{det}(A^2) \geq 0$, $n$ must be even in order to get $(-1)^n=1$

Comment: That's right. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949189/a-is-n-times-n-real-matrix-with-a2-i-to-prove-that-n-is-even, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007643/let-a-be-an-n-times-n-matrix-with-real-entries-such-that-a2-i-0-then, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471445/prove-properties-of-a2-i